# White Dots in Game

Tags: display

I have a gigabyte 7900 card which give me flashing lights in new games.
please if it software problem or anything i'll appreciate if you guide me through this.
i'll attach the pics.

anti aliasing on

[image]

anti aliasing off

[image]

---

game like ac unity , ac syndicate, ryse son of rome

my os is windows 7 x64

7900 readeon
384 bit
3gb gddr5

---

also i should mention i tried another os but its all the same..

Comment: what is your OS? What are those new games? A bit more details on your graphic card would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many people have experienced white dots, either in games, or in every day tasks. If it is only in games, then this means that you are running high settings on a game that your card cannot handle so well if you run it with AA or bad game rendering engine affects some cards.

Some people had bad VRAM, and others corrupt files. But in your case it is running without dots when AA is off.

This has always been around since AA was introduced

You can also get it in game engines even without AA, like Crysis Warhead at max settings you get white dots around the foilage with on some cards.

You don't have a defective card(s) that's just how some rendering bugs pop up on some video cards.